# Why did the scala compiler not flag what appears to not be a tail-recursive function?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I have marked the method sameLength to check and optimize for tail-recursion. I feel last operation in sameLength method is not sameLength. It is &&. The && is in the else clause. Why does the compiler not flag this. Since the compiler does not flag it I assume it is indeed tail-recursive. Can someone define tail-recursion for me? I have the wrong definition in my mind.

```
  import scala.annotation.tailrec


  object TestTailRec extends App{

    @tailrec
    def sameLength[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]) : Boolean = {
      if(xs.isEmpty) ys.isEmpty
      else ys.nonEmpty && sameLength(xs.tail, ys.tail)
    }

    println(sameLength(List(1,2,3), List(1,2,3)))

  }
```

Comment: I don't know if it is what the compiler does, but boolean expressions are calculated by the "short circuit" method: if ys.nonEmpty is false then there is no need to calculate sameLength. If it is true then it will return the result of sameLength, making it indeed tail-recursive

Answer (score 2):

[The spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#class-boolean) defines the `&&` method for `Boolean`.

Since `Boolean` is a value class, the `if/else` expression is inlined.

Since the `p` parameter is by-name, it's not evaluated first.

Your intuition is confirmed by the strict version:

```
scala> @tailrec def f(i: Int): Boolean = false & f(i)
<console>:16: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method f: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's refactor your method a little, without changing its meaning:

```
def sameLength[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]) : Boolean = {
  if(xs.isEmpty) ys.isEmpty
  else if (ys.isEmpty) false else
  sameLength(xs.tail, ys.tail)
}
```

I think it's now clear this is tail recursive